# sizeof() problems with empty class inheritance

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h> 

class X 
{
};

class Y
{
     // long x; // case A)
     // X x;    // case B)
};

class Z : public Y, public X
{
};

int main() {
     Z z;
     printf("%d %d %d\n", 
        sizeof(Z), sizeof(Y), (char*)static_cast<X*>(&z) - (char*)&z);
     return 0;
}
```

Why is the output as follows after uncommenting either case A or case B:

A: `4 4 4`
B: `2 1 2`

Why is `sizeof(Y) != sizeof(Z)` in case B), but is equal in case A). Can anyone explain?

Comment: Multiple inheritance implementation details are complex. Comparing the relative sizes of declared classes isn't going to be terribly insightful. Also, every compiler may be different, what are you using?

Answer (score 4):

My memory is vague on this, but I think it's because the two X sub-objects of Z (the base class X and Y::x) must have different addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Empty classes still are required to have a size of at least 1.  But that doesn't mean that they have to impart that size to their sub-classes.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem on empty base class problem and found the explanation.

ISO/IEC 14882:2003
10-5

> A base class subobject may be of zero size (clause 9); however, two
>   subobjects that have the same class type and that belong to the same
>   most derived object must not be allocated at the same address (5.10).

this means if object of Y has two subobjects of X, then both X MUST have different address(they must be 2 different objects with different address).

BTW, empty base class doesn't have to be 0 sized(it says MAY BE) until C++11, which claims it as required, more reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo

Answer (score 0):

Just a little addition to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class X
{
};

class Y
{
    // long x; // case A)
    public:
        X x;    // case B)
};

class Z : public Y, public X
{
};

int main() {
    Z z;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof(Z), sizeof(Y), (char*)static_cast<X*>(&z) - (char*)&z);

    printf("%p %p %p %p\n", &z, static_cast<Y*>(&z), static_cast<X*>(&z), &z.x);

    return 0;
}
```

In my machine I get:

```
2 1 1
0x7fff8876fcb0 0x7fff8876fcb0 0x7fff8876fcb1 0x7fff8876fcb0
   ^^Z             ^^Y             ^^X            Z::x
```

So, the two bytes are taken by `X` objects. One is the base class, the other is the one present in `Y`.